# Optimization of a function to find min and max element

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

I have the following code but I need to optimize it for better running time.Is it possible.
Here minLR takes out min element from left to right
minRL other from right to left. I am not able to use the standard library function as I have to iterate in reverse direction also.
I have to increment the min element of the array from 'left' to'right' if 'i' is odd and increment array by finding min element from 'r' to' l' if 'i' is even.
m is quite large.

```
int minLR(int *arr,int s){
    int ind=0;
    int min=arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<s;i++){
        if(min>arr[i]){min=arr[i];ind=i;}
    }
    arr[ind]++;
    return ind;
}

int minRL(int *arr,int s){
    int ind=s-1;
    int min=arr[s-1];
    for(int i=s-2;i>=0;i--){
        if(min>arr[i]){ min=arr[i];ind=i;}
    }
    arr[ind]++;
    return ind;
}

for(int i=1;i<=m;i++){
    if(i%2==0){
        ind=minRL(arr,n);    
    }
    if(i%2!=0){
        ind=minLR(arr,n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do better then O(n) when searching minimum, maximum values in an unsorted datastructure. This is the same as saying you will have to check each value at least once.

Comment: Your formatting is atrocious.

Comment: You should consider using the Standard C++ [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) algorithm.

Comment: or std::minmax_element in <algorithm>

Comment: Is there a scope for the std::minmax algo to search the array from right to leftas i need to search the array and increment the values both ways.

Comment: @911 Yes, I confused these two.

Comment: @reaper1 If you use a STL container instead of an array, you can use reverse iterators.

Comment: I don't understand your for loop:  whay are you calculating the minimum so many times constantly calling the same fuctions with the same parameters (ok with a small variant for odd and even iterations) ?  And is there a reason for you to modify array elements when searching the minimum ??

Comment: It is a part of a problem where i have to increment th min element of the array from  ' l 'to' r '   if    'i' is odd and increment array index by finding min element from ' r' to' l' if  'i' is even.

Comment: Ok, then you're not only looking ofr the minimum/maximum and the standard library won't help you here.  Maybe you should edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @reaper1 as I now have understood your problem better, I have proposed an alternative to your approach with an optimized algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of finding minimum or maximum or both minimum and maximum is **always O(n)**.  This can't be improved if the array has to remain unsorted.

### Using your original approach

You can eventuelly improve a little bit the performance by combining cleverly the search for minimum AND maximum at the same time, using slightly improved alogrithm as explained [in this article](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/05/21/computer-algorithms-minimum-and-maximum/).

You'd then spare n/2-2 comparison at each min/max search. But this won't change the order of magnitude of O(n) of each search. So overall your algorithm will stay at O(n²).

### Alternative respecting your approach

The alternative is to use a shadow sorted data structure pointing to the elements in the unsorted table.  Here an implementation based on standard vectors and algorithms:

```
vector<int*> myshadow(n);  // sorted shadow structure 
transform(arr, arr+n, myshadow.begin(), [](int& x)->int* { return &x; });

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    sort(myshadow.begin(), myshadow.end(), [](int* a, int*b)->bool { return *a < *b; }); 
    // now myshadow[0] holds the smallest element:  
    if(i % 2 == 0)
        minRLi(myshadow, n);
    else minLRi(myshadow, n);
}
```

The result is the same than with your original algorithm, with the following functions replicating in an optimized manner the left and right search (the loop only iterates through the few smallest elements) :

```
int* minLRi(vector<int *>arr, int s){
    int ind = 0;
    int* min = arr[0]; // min shall be the smallest element address of the same minimal value (leftmost)
    for(int i = 1; i<s && *arr[0]==*arr[i]; i++){
        if(min>arr[i]){ min = arr[i]; ind = i; }
    }
    (*arr[ind])++;
    return arr[ind]; 
}
int* minRLi(vector<int *>arr, int s){
    int ind = 0;
    int* min = arr[0]; // min shall be the largest element address of the same minimal value (rightmost)
    for(int i = 1; i<s && *arr[0] == *arr[i]; i++){
        if(min<arr[i]){ min = arr[i]; ind = i; }
    }
    (*arr[ind])++;
    return arr[ind];
}
```

### Optimizing further

Now I assumed that `std::sort()` is extremely efficient when re-sorting an almost sorted vector. Experimentation showed me that at lest on my MSVC2013 this was not true at all. PPerformance results where catastrophic.

So I slightly modified the code for optimizing resorting.

**The optimised code can be [viewed and tried online here](http://ideone.com/ZO61lm)**

### Conclusion

I have no time to analyse it in depth, but I think the complexity should be around O(nlog(n)).

Practical experimentation with 200 000 random elements (MSVC 2013, release, i7 processor) showed:

- your original approach took 30 seconds (1 345 millions of iterations !!)
- the shadow alternative took  32 milliseconds (631 thousands iterations)

Comment: What data structure would you suggest in order to solve the problem above.Initially the array is initialized to zeros. @christophie

Comment: Well I don't know the overall problem you're solving, If you could sort the array, it would help.  If not, it could perhap's be interesting to build a sorted doubly linked list to access very quicky to the min or max element at the minor cost of updating the postion of the incremented elements

Comment: @reaper1 I've updated my answer.  There's a link to online code, with integrated benchmarking.  The results will interes you: improving by a factor of 1000 ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

One much more efficient solution (assuming very large n) is to first transcribe the data to a std::map of std::set and then work on that:

The key to the map would be a value that appears one or more times in the array.  The payload of the map would be the set of all places that value appears in the array.  That is easy and relatively efficient to build.

Then it is easy to find the direction independent min (first element in the map) and take the left or right element from that min set and move it to the next higher min set.

If you used a priority queue instead of map, the complexity of programming would be a little higher and the efficiency a little better.

So far as I understand, a standard priority queue does not give you easy access to the second priority element (access it, modify it, possibly insert a new second priority while leaving the first priority untouched).  I usually invent my own priority queue to get extra features like that, so I'm not sure whether the standard one can be pushed that far or whether you would need to invent your own.